# Are build.sbt and project/Build.scala redundant?

Tags: playframework, sbt

Actually I would like to keep

```
name := "projectName"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

in the **build.sbt** and all my real dependencies in the **project/Build.scala**, is it possible/advisable ?

What about the tests in that setting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** `.sbt`s and `project/*.scala`s are complementary and they serve different purposes (yet very similar for simple cases). Use `in ThisBuild` in `*.sbt` to have the settings belong to the build.

They are not as they serve different purposes (yet in many use cases they can seem similar or even redundant).

`build.sbt` files can be in *any* project in a multi-module project build and they set up settings for the project they're in.

`project/Build.scala` can only live in the top-level (aka `root`) project and is to *share* settings across projects. The settings are not shared automatically and you'll have to "attach" them to projects using `settings` method call on `sbt.Project` or `project` macro.

If you want to have a single `build.sbt` that would set up settings for the entire build, use `in ThisBuild` and you're done. Call the file `globals.sbt` so it's easily distinguishable from a command line (the name's arbitrary, thought, provided the file extension is `.sbt`).

```
name in ThisBuild := "projectName"

version in ThisBuild := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```